# Calculate Sql Select Count with OFFSET FETCH

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to count rows in select before OFFSET FETCH. But as far as i know there is no way to get total rows of the query in select. That's why you've to copy whole Select to just count rows before offset fetch. Is this a usual way of doing, or some better approaches exists? I have kind of a query:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Id = Table1.Table2Id
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Id = Table1.Table3Id
INNER JOIN Table4 on Table4.Id = Table1.Table4Id
WHERE [Table1].Amount >= @Count
OFFSET (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

But as query grows there will be more duplication and in case of any change all devs has to remember change both queries which to me weird. Currently i'm doing separate query for count and another for getting rows.

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Id = Table1.Table2Id
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Id = Table1.Table3Id
INNER JOIN Table4 on Table4.Id = Table1.Table4Id
WHERE [Table1].Amount >= @Count

SELECT *
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Id = Table1.Table2Id
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Id = Table1.Table3Id
INNER JOIN Table4 on Table4.Id = Table1.Table4Id
WHERE [Table1].Amount >= @Count
OFFSET (@PageNumber - 1) * @PageSize ROWS
FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

How you guys solving it?

Comment: How are you executing the queries? Can't you get the count from your executing code?

Comment: You can always get the total count in the same query using windowed finctions: `COUNT(1) OVER()`, but I doubt that's what you need

Comment: also you may want to look at @@ROWCOUNT after running your query to see how many rows are returned : `SELECT @@ROWCOUNT`

Comment: @eshirvana Can you post it as anwer, i'll mark it resolved

Comment: Look into keyset paging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also want to look at the `@@ROWCOUNT` global variable in SQL Server after running your original query to see how many rows are returned :

```
SELECT @@ROWCOUNT
```

This also can be helpful when you run `UPDATE` / `INSERT` as well.

See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for more info.

\

Update Aug 2023 :

also another solution is to use window function , to avoid running the query twice:

```
SELECT * FROM (
   SELECT * , count(*) over () as cnt 
   FROM Table1 
   INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Id = Table1.Table2Id
   INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Id = Table1.Table3Id
   INNER JOIN Table4 on Table4.Id = Table1.Table4Id
) t WHERE t.Amount >= cnt
```

Comment: I do not understand how this helps the opening question? The OP is asking how to avoid writing 2 selects with the same WHERE clause and the accepted answer suggests stick a third query in between the 2 select statements to get the row count! 
The first query is returning the row count anyway. If you skip the first query, run only the second query and then get a @rowcount you will get the count of fetch/offset restricted count which is not the total records count. So this answer is not helping to avoid writing duplicate where clause and 2 SELECT queries.

Answer (score 1):

(1) if you just need to see how many records was returned you can run this as 2nd query:

`SELECT @@ROWCOUNT`

(2) in case you actually need to do more with the data, you can move your main piece of code to a view

```
CREATE VIEW YourView 
AS 
SELECT *
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Id = Table1.Table2Id
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Id = Table1.Table3Id
INNER JOIN Table4 on Table4.Id = Table1.Table4Id
```

and than just select from it multiple times:

```
select count (*) from YourView where WHERE [Table1].Amount >= @Count
select * from YourView where WHERE [Table1].Amount >= @Count
```

(3) or you can insert into #tempTable or @tableVariable

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Id = Table1.Table2Id
INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Id = Table1.Table3Id
INNER JOIN Table4 on Table4.Id = Table1.Table4Id
WHERE [Table1].Amount >= @Count
```

and than select from them like from table or view:

```
select count(*) from #TempTable
select * from #TempTable
```

(4) Common table expression (the WITH clause) suggested in the other answer posted by Alec
wont actually work for your scenario since you need 2 separate results and CTE only allows single select to it.

note: all syntax provided for tsql (MS Sql Server), you might need to adjust it for your DB server.

Answer (score -2):

You can use a WITH clause.

```sql
WITH query_name AS (SELECT *
                 FROM Table1 
                 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table2.Id = Table1.Table2Id
                 INNER JOIN Table3 ON Table3.Id = Table1.Table3Id
                 INNER JOIN Table4 on Table4.Id = Table1.Table4Id
                 WHERE [Table1].Amount >= @Count)

SELECT * FROM query_name;
SELECT count(*) FROM query_name;
```

Comment: Except the second query can't use the CTE